# launchd plist format for running a command at a specific time on a weekday

Tags: launchd, plist

I'm trying to run a command at 10 minutes after 2am every weekday only.  In my `launchd` `.plist` file, how can I specify this?

I don't want it to run every 2 hours and 10 minutes, just once every weekday at the specified time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few caveats with creating launchd .plist files.  I'll summarize them below:

1. Each Weekday must be a  entry specified in an  placed in the **StartCalendarInterval** dictionary entry.
2. Weekdays go from 1 to 5.  Sunday is 0 and 7 (I know, right?)
3. You have to know how you want your item to run and place the `.plist` in the appropriate directories/folders:

   1. `~/Library/LaunchAgents` - Specific to the user.  Will run when the user is logged in.
   2. `/Library/LaunchAgents` - Specific to all users.  Will run when the user(s) is(are) logged in.
   3. `/Library/LaunchDaemons` - Runs regardless if user(s) is(are) logged in.  Must use `sudo` to load `.plist`

My preference is #3 (load as a LaunchDaemon) so my script will get executed whether I am logged in or not.  When using as a LaunchDameon, you must use `sudo` to load the `.plist`:

`sudo launchctl load com.user.fileCleanup.plist`

Note:  As for the naming convention in my example, I like to use `com.user.<NAME_OF_MY_SCRIPT>.plist`  This helps me in identifying and debugging any issues should they arise and keeps with the Apple naming convention of `com.apple.some-app.plist`  This is entirely optional on your part.

Below is a script that I am using to clean up work files (I modified it for your specific time parameters). You can edit this file with your favorite text editor (I use [Komodo Edit](http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/)), but TextEdit or even `nano` or `vi` from the command line will work.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.fileCleanup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/allan/Documents/Scripts/Unix/fileCleanup.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <!--  Weekdays are 1 - 5; Sunday is 0 and 7   -->
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>

</dict>
</plist>
```

#### Bonus Footage....

This next part is optional...

So that I can get some feedback that my scripts executed and what the result was, I created a small AppleScript function that invokes the `display notification` (it's quite simple for my needs, but obviously could be improved).

```
on run argv
    
    set Message to item 1 of argv
    set Title to item 2 of argv
    set aud to item 3 of argv
    set STitle to "Terminal"
    set Snd to "Blow.aiff"
    
    
    if (aud = "sound") then
        
        display notification Message with title Title subtitle STitle sound name Snd
    else
        display notification Message with title Title subtitle STitle
    end if
    
end run
```

Within my script, I check for success or failure, depending on what that is (i.e. a file existing in a particular directory), it will generate a notification.  If not, another notification, but this time with sound!

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "$SOURCE" ]
then
    scp -q "$SOURCE" "$TARGET"
    osascript $ASCRIPT_DIR/notify.scpt "Podcast Transfered successfully" "$TITLE -- SUCCESS" "nosound"
else
    osascript $ASCRIPT_DIR/notify.scpt "The file $TARGET does not exist" "$TITLE -- ERROR" "sound"
fi
```

Here's the sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example *.plist* file to cover executing at 2:10 AM every weekday.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.hello</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>say</string>
        <string>hello</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

If you do not want to hand write the `launchd` *.plist* file, a program like [Lingon X](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) can be quite helpful as it will facilitate the loading/unloading of the *.plist* file too.

Answer (score 2):

The command you need is Start CalendarInterval

The easy way is use a program like [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) or [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) to write and load the plist.

This example runs /usr/bin/env at the time you want. There is no shortcut for all weekdays so you have to list the days Sunday is 0. I have shown Monday and Tuesday as an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.job</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/env</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```