# how to start a mysql server on login

Tags: terminal, sudo, mysql

I currently use Valet to develop sites, and many of those sites need SQL databases.  To host SQL databases, I run a mariaDB server from the Terminal.  In order to start the MySQL server so that I can connect to the databases, I run the command: 
`sudo mysql.server start`
I want the server to start on login, so normally I would just have this command execute on login, but it requires the sudo command.  What do I change and how do I change it so that I do not need the sudo part of the command and I can just start the server on login?

Comment: See if [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26476391/3487310) helps.  It's not a duplicate question but it has info that might assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a `launchd` .plist, copy it to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and let the system handle it for you.

Sample .plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.user.startMySQL</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>mysql.server</string>
          <string>start</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I prefer to use the file naming convention `com.user.<name of function>.plist` when naming them so I can easily identify what is loaded and what is not.

Next, you need to load this .plist as `root` so it runs as `root`

`$ sudo launchctl load com.user.startMySQL.plist`

To verify that it has loaded you can issue the command `sudo launchctl list` and the command `mysql` to initiate a connection to the MySQL service.

*Please note that this is just a simple example - you may wish to create a script to check to see if `mysqld` is already running before launching it.*

Comment: but it sounds like I will have to run this command every time I want to use the server, so I dont see how this is better than what I do now.

actually I was just looking for which permissions or owner to change to make this command runnable by me without sudo, so that I can then just execute this command on login somehow.

Comment: You only have to do this once.  It will launch MySQL automatically every time you log in

Comment: oh ok thanks

Tell me if understand this correctly: 'launchd' is a daemon that starts at launch and runs every job in 'launchctl'.

In order to add a job to launchctl, define it in a .plist file and copy that file to ~/Library/LaunchAgents, then load the plist into launchctl with$ launchctl load com.user.startMySQL.plist and the reason a path does not have to be given in the command is that a file name is sufficient as long as it is a file in the 'LaunchAgents' directory because launchctl looks in that directory.  Once loaded into launchctl, launchd will run the new job on login.

Comment: That's basically correct.  I have written about `launchd` in more detail in this [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249446/launchd-plist-format-for-running-a-command-at-a-specific-time-on-a-weekday/249452#249452)  Personally, I wourld start your server on boot rather than on login, but whatever suits you best...