# Show dialog at login (bash script)

Tags: applescript, bash, cron

The idea is that when somebody logs in to my Mac, a popup will show up and the date/time are written to a log.

I run the bash script from a cron job:

```
 @reboot ~/Develop/login.sh
```

(I know about launchd but choose to use cron, much easier)

the login.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript <<EOD
  tell application "System Events"
  activate
  display dialog "Unauthorized Login" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon caution with title "WARNING!"
  end tell
EOD

echo "$(date) LogIn Alert" >> ~/Develop/login.log
```

I can execute the script with ./login.sh. All working well, the dialog is shown and login time is written to the log.

But when restarting my Mac the login date/time is written to the file (so the cron job is working), but the dialog is not popping up.

(I did look at the question [Run AppleScript from bash script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103621/run-applescript-from-bash-script))

So my question is how to show this dialog when rebooting my Mac?
(macOS 10.12.3)

Comment: I assume you do know about the "last" command - just to make sure that's not what you want. Also, I would use "syslog" to monitor user logins. See e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143864/monitor-all-login-attempts

Comment: No, the problem is that the dialog is not showing after a reboot

Comment: Just out of curiosity...why are you allowing other people to log on in the first place?

Comment: Would rather not discuss that here

Comment: Just that I get you right - you want the dialog to appear when the computer reboots, NOT when you try to log in ? - because that's what you try to do with the code above. You want a popup with no user logged in, right? You can set the displayed message in preferences, but that's not a popup, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203580. System Events are not available at the login screen the way you attempt it I think.

Comment: No, after logging in. I use the word reboot because that is when the cron job is running

Comment: Exactly - reboot is when the cron job is running. Before login. That's the problem.

Comment: If you want to do this *on login* you either have to have it run as a "Startup Item" or use `launchd`.  `cron` only works on time intervals, not on events like someone logging into a machine.

Comment: Though not exact, it's a possible duplicate of [how to start a mysql server on login](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268691/how-to-start-a-mysql-server-on-login).  The relevance is that this question asks the same thing:  *how to run a script at login*.

Comment: The question is how to run a _script_, not an _application_. That's something different, the solution in the link won't work. But it should be renamed to "at login" instead of "at reboot".

Comment: @user2707001 - there's no difference between running a script or an app through `launchd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run your script above not as a cron job but as described in this post (*) :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac

Make sure not to confuse running things on the login screen and running things on user login like in the question below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842016/launch-shell-script-on-login-in-mac-os-os-x?noredirect=1&lq=1

Still, there is no need for you to log user logins as they are automatically logged. See "man last" and "cat /var/log/authd.log".

(*) Relevant part of the linked post above - or use launchd, as described in the link

```
start Automator.app
Select "Application"
click "Show library" in the toolbar (if hidden)
Add "Run shell script" (from the Actions/Utilities)
Copy&paste your script into the window
Test it
Save somewhere, for example you can make an "Applications" folder in your HOME (you will get an your_name.app)
Go to System Preferences -> Accounts -> Login items
Add this app
```

Comment: It's better to put the relevant bits here and then post a link for more reference.  Links often go stale making the answer useless.

Comment: Thats it, thanks. After all the cron job is not usable for what I wanted and I need to use launchd as described in the first link.

Comment: Sorry, do not have enough reputation to upvote

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need System Events just to display a dialog, nor can you strictly speaking 'activate' it...
try just

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript <<EOD
  tell me to display dialog "Unauthorized Login" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon caution with title "WARNING!"
EOD

echo "$(date) LogIn Alert" >> ~/Develop/login.log
```

I can't really test it as I'm totally clueless on cron/bash/osascript itself, but that would be all you'd need for a regular Applescript to display a dialog.

If that doesn't work, then the next step would be to set it up in Automator, as an Application, then set to launch at login.