# Mounting a Network share on login (There was a problem connecting to this server)

Tags: macos, sharing, mount, login

I have a new piece of software that I've installed that relies on a mounted network share in order to operate. The network share is a hosted MacMini Server, connecting over SMB.

I've added the share to the user's login items, but whenever the computer boots and is logged in, I see the (There was a problem connecting to the server "MacMini") and it doesn't mount.

However, if I simply acknowledge that message, then do Command+K and mount it manually, it will mount without issue.

I've already saved the credentials to KeyChain, I'm just not sure why it wont mount at login.

If anyone has any ideas. Much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look a this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268691/how-to-start-a-mysql-server-on-login/268692#268692  It's exactly the same premise, except instead of running the mysql server, you run the mount command.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with it for a couple of days myself, and finally found a solution.

In Automator, I made a simple three step Application that waits for a few seconds (using "Pause") before trying to connect to the network share. I believe the problem is related to the (in my case wireless) network connection not being completely established when the login items run immediately after login.

The Application consists of three steps:

- Pause for 5 seconds
- Get specified Servers "smb://HOSTNAME/SHARENAME"
- Connect to Servers

HOSTNAME and SHARENAME should be replaced with your own parameters. The choice of 5 seconds is arbitrary (and probably is likely dependent on one's own specific conditions) but it works on my own Mac Mini 2011.

[image: Screenshot of previously described application]

Please note that running this script only works when the network share is not already connected, you need to unmount before running the application for testing purposes.

Update: Now that I've had a few days of experience with this script I've found that it works sometimes and sometimes not, my guess is still that the wireless network isn't ready to connect and that it fails because of that. The reasons why are unclear to say the least, increasing the Pause timer duration definitely helps though.