# How to completely block specific Wi-Fi SSID on macOS?

Tags: macos, wifi

I'm looking for a way to totally blacklist a Wi-Fi network (by SSID) in macOS.

And no, I promise you that I really (truly!) do not need to just have the computer "forget it" by removing it from the network list. I need to completely and  totally prevent the computer from connecting to a certain network entirely.

It's super, crazy easy on Windows. Is there any way to do this on a Mac?

Comment: @bret7600 I just need to block a certain SSID. Like this in Windows: http://mywindowshub.com/add-remove-wireless-network-allowed-blocked-filter-list-windows-10/

Comment: Does this have something to do with this? http://www.oregonlive.com/portland/index.ssf/2017/10/whats_that_about_cops_wi-fi_ne.html

Comment: Ha! Nope, but funny article

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no blacklist function (that I know of) but there are a couple of simple workarounds detailed below.

#### Restrict to Admins Only

Your first option would be to set up networking and restrict it so only Admins can join networks (*Network Settings →  WiFi Adapter → Advanced*)

[image]

The caveat here is that the user can no longer be an admin.

#### Progmatically remove network

If you’d prefer this automated, your second option is to have a terminal command run periodically:

```
networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en1 SSID
```

If the SSID doesn't exist, it will just error out without any issues.  If it does exist, it will remove it from the preferred (saved) network list.

You could put this is a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

SSID=MyBannedSSID

net=$(networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks en1 | grep ${SSID} | cut -f2)
ap=$(networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -c 2-)

# Remove Network if exists in saved networks
if [ "$net" = "$SSID" ]
  then networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en1 ${SSID}
  sleep 5               # Sleep 5 seconds to allow removal to complete.

else echo "No Network"
fi

#Power cycle wireless adapter if connected to banned network
if [ "$ap" = "$SSID" ]
  then  networksetup -setairportpower en1 off
        sleep 2            #Sleep 2 seconds for service to die
        networksetup -setairportpower en1 on
fi
```

Then, use `cron` or [`launchd`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249446/launchd-plist-format-for-running-a-command-at-a-specific-time-on-a-weekday/249452#249452) (preferred) to run it periodically.  The caveat is that while they may join the network, it will eventually (per your schedule) delete it.  The time interval will be entirely up to you.

You have to run this as root (meaning put in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` if using `launchd`) otherwise it will ask you for a password every time.

**What the script is doing**

- Checks to see if banned SSID is saved
- Removes the saved network if it exists
- Power cycles the airport card if it's attached to the banned SSID

Comment: Nice work! You must suggest it to Apple since they seem to ignore that there are a lot of trapped Wi-Fi networks in the real world.

Answer (score 5):

I've just tested this and it works!

You need the app Apple Congifurator 2, it's on the App Store, made by Apple.

Create a new profile, in the wifi section create a new payload. Fill out the information, including the correct security type. Set the password to something wrong. *Uncheck the 'Auto Join' option.*

Now, why does this work? The profile sets settings which cannot be changed by the user and so if you configure it with a password the user will not be able to uninstall the profile. Since you have configured the wrong password for the profile, the computer won't be able to connect to the network and will show an incorrect password popup. That's where the "auto join" setting comes in. By configuring the device to not automatically join that network, the device will only attempt to connect to it when the user selects it out of the menu. Since the user can't change the stored password they won't be given the option to try a new password and so won't be able to connect. With auto join off, you also won't get tons of "incorrect password" errors on the device any time the network is in range since it won't bother to connect to it.

[image: Example config]

Comment: "Set the password to something wrong." - if I understood the question correctly and the network that is to be avoided is malicious, it will gladly accept *any* password whatsoever, meaning this "solution" would actually make it much likely to accidentally connect to that network. Beware!

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience but what I would try:
setup a new acccount, give it administrator rights,
login in this new account, go to SystemPreferences, ParentalControls:
in there set parental controls for your main account, set the access to ...aruba... as forbidden.

Comment: I'm not sure what section you are trying to set the access under... websites? Could you clarify? I can't find anything in this section that allows you to restrict wifi access.