# Limit - not disable - Remember joined Wi-Fi locations

Tags: mac, network, wifi, high-sierra

I'm building an entirely new corporate infrastructure - ATM I have ~200 macs expanding to over 600 in the next year.

I need to configure the Wi-Fi with two locations:
Corporate Network
Off - Site

I'd like the Corporate Network location to - not remember joined networks and the Off-site location to be able to remember if they're at home then roaming.

The reason is - when in the office - there are open access points at nearby buildings that the Macs sometimes pick up - therefore the system doesn't join the corporate Wi-Fi. The users find they're unable to route anywhere and open a ticket

They're all on 10.13.6

By default - the remember joined networks apply to any location.

Can I do this with a configuration profile?

If so - how? I haven't found the correct commands

Or - is there a - defaults write - statement to do such as thing

Comment: See this related post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/302081/119271

Answer (score 1):

I use profiles to set the default WiFi networks, (with the help of an apple server)
This way, users don't have to add any networks, apart from their home WiFi.

I also have a little python script to re-order the WiFi so that "my" networks are always the top two ones. This scripts runs as a logout script also via a profile.
Script that I use:
https://gist.github.com/pudquick/fcbdd3924ee230592ab4

As far as I know, you can not prevent the Mac from joining "some" networks only,
but perhaps you can with a 3rd party tool.

Comment: You'd recommend a script to ensure the corporate network is always first?  Sounds like this is the easiest route