# Is cron command supposed to work like this?

Tags: high-sierra, cron

I've set up `cron` to run a script hourly but when I reboot cron does not work. Does this mean that I should run cron whenever I boot into my Mac? The cron command which I use `cron 5 * * * * path/to/script.sh`. Is there any problem with cron or I this kind of behaviour expected?

Comment: `cron` has been deprecated in favor of `launchd`.  Have a look at this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271) for a primer on how to setup a `launchd` job that executes at a given interval.

Comment: @Allan I know that `launchd` makes the job easier but like `cron` because I just have to type one line. I am lazy :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to call `cron` directly. Any commands you want to run need to be added to the `crontab` of the user they should run as. You can edit your `crontab` by running

```
crontab -e
```

or, if you are an admin user and want to edit the `crontab` of another user,

```
crontab -u USERNAME -e
```

PS: Run `man 5 crontab` for details about the format of the file, what kind of special commands you can use, and some samples. `5 * * * * /path/to/script` seems to be ok though.

Answer (score 5):

On macOS High Sierra (and perhaps earlier), `cron` is disabled in some configurations. There is, however, still a LaunchDaemon for it.

Check to see if cron is enabled:

```
sudo launchctl list | grep cron
```

You should see `com.vix.cron.plist` if cron is running. If cron is *not* running, you should do:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist
```

That will start `cron`, and the `-w` switch will make sure it starts after reboots as well.