# Add a permanent static route on Ventura

Tags: network, ventura

I must add a static route on my machine running macOS 13.5 (Ventura).

Online, many tutorials explain how to do so (they all use the same procedure), but I can't make it work. Here is what I have done

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
Thunderbolt Bridge
Wi-Fi

sudo networksetup -setadditionalroutes Wi-Fi 10.244.1.10 255.255.255.255 193.156.100.100


networksetup -getadditionalroutes Wi-Fi
10.244.1.10 255.255.255.255 193.156.100.100
```

After this, when I try to connect to `10.244.1.10` I get

> Unable to connect
> An error occurred during a connection to 10.244.1.10.

However, If I set the route with `sudo route -n add -net 10.244.1.10/32 193.156.100.100`, I can reach the site, but (of course) the route is gone after I reboot the machine.

Am I missing something here?

I have read [Creating a static route through a specific interface](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390635/creating-a-static-route-through-a-specific-interface), but I don't see how it solves my problem. Please. help me understand that.

Comment: What part of the linked dupe don’t you understand?

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for the reply. I don't see what the accepted solution may solve my issue. It uses `route add ...`, which adds a temporary route.

Comment: The `route add` command sets the route, but's it temporary.  The answer goes on to say that you need to add it to a LaunchAgent or LaunchDaemon, depending on when you want it to load - when a user logs in or on boot for all users.  You put that command in a script and set up a plist.  All the instructions are there.

Comment: So, `networksetup` does not work, and I have to add the route temporarily every time I boot the machine. I see, thanks. Just out of curiosity, since `networksetup` doesn't work, why do all the tutorials out there refer to it? Thanks.