# Can't open crontab

Tags: cron

I tried running `crontab` on my Mac for the first time and got the following:

```
$ crontab -e
crontab: no crontab for User - using an empty one
crontab: subl -w: No such file or directory
crontab: "subl -w" exited with status 1
```

I've never used crontab on my Mac and have no idea why it's trying to reach the sublime command line tool.

However, if I type `subl -w` into my console, sublime opens right up.

What's going on here?

Comment: What is the value of `EDITOR` (run `echo $EDITOR`)?

Comment: That returns `subl -w`. Can't remember when I changed that, but this is the first issue I've had with it.

Comment: Also, `crontab` is deprecated in macOS.  You should start transitioning over to [`lauchd`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271)

Comment: What does `which subl` show?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem with `crontab` and the `EDITOR` variable which you must have set to `subl -w`. To quote from the man page of `bbedit`:

```
Some tools (notably crontab), will not work correctly if your EDITOR variable 
consists of multiple terms. You can work around this by creating a simple shell 
script that calls bbedit -w, then using the shell script as your EDITOR. e.g.:

                #!/bin/sh
                bbedit -w "$@"
```

Of course, for Sublime Text you can change `bbedit` to `subl` in that script.

Comment: Actually further testing revealed that it didn't work properly, you need to use the script as the "-w" is required otherwise crontab doesn't wait for your edits.