# launchD runs script every hour in between 8:00 to 17:00 on weekdays

Tags: macos, mac

launchD runs script every hour in between 8:00 to 17:00 hours on weekdays Mon to Fri.

8 to 17:00 = 9 times in a Day.
Mon - Friday = 5 days
Do I have to add  `StartCalendarInterval` 9 X 5 = 45 times or is there any other easy sensible way to it?

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>08</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>  
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Sorry if qus make you confuse. I just want to run a script every hour in between 8AM to 5PM on weekdays Mon to Fri.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [launchd plist format for running a command at a specific time on a weekday](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249446/launchd-plist-format-for-running-a-command-at-a-specific-time-on-a-weekday)

Comment: Yes, you have to.  You could also run it everyday and have the script itself check if it's a weekend and exit gracefully.