# launchctl config file location?

Tags: launchd, plist, netboot

I'm trying to configure a NetBoot image so that a script will automatically launch on the target machine after it boots from the image

I've been using this article as a reference:

https://medium.com/@fahimhossain_16989/adding-startup-scripts-to-launch-daemon-on-mac-os-x-sierra-10-12-6-7e0318c74de1

my question is: when the following command is run...

```
# -w flag permanently adds the plist to the Launch Daemon
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.startup.plist
```

...where is the resulting permanent configuration entry stored on the hard drive?

**To clarify: I'm not asking for the location of the .plist file, I'm asking how/where does the system remember the .plist files that you've configured to run on startup using the 'sudo launchctl load' command?**

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: I think [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271) might address your question.  Let me know if this is the info you're looking for.

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly load your daemon in this situation; plists in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ are auto-loaded at system startup (provided their format, permissions etc are correct). You only need `launchctl load` if you want to load a daemon *after* startup, or if it's been explicitly disabled and you want to override that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You shouldn't need to explicitly load your daemon in this situation;
>   plists in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ are auto-loaded at system startup
>   (provided their format, permissions etc are correct). You only need
>   launchctl load if you want to load a daemon after startup, or if it's
>   been explicitly disabled and you want to override that.

– Gordon Davisson