# How to run a sudo command on startup - launch daemon help

Tags: terminal, audio, startup, sudo

I have a sound problem on my 2010 Mac mini. I found a solution that uses a `sudo` command in the Terminal app. But this method only works one time, so when the computer turns off and then back on, you need to start over..

Please bear with me - I'm new in this Mac universe.

From this site, I’ve found that you can use a Launch Daemon to execute it.

I can't seem to figure out a working file.

My `sudo` command for the sound fix is:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

After that type:

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

Remember, `sudo` requires an administrator password.

My idea here is to run this at startup so I don't have to type it every time.

Can someone help me write it?

Comment: A few things..it’s not a “sudo command”. `sudo` allows you to run any command as *another* user, in this case root.  Since you mention running as a launch daemon, then those commands are *already* run as root, so `sudo` isn’t necessary. There are [existing posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249446/launchd-plist-format-for-running-a-command-at-a-specific-time-on-a-weekday/249452#249452) on how to do this

Comment: You just need to have the service run as root. [This](https://www.launchd.info) should have everything you need to know.

Comment: I understand that you’re new to Mac’s, but unloading and reloading a driver (that’s what kexts are), especially on start up is way outside the norm for *any* computer.  It’s better to address the underlying issue rather than budge together a “fix” that doesn’t really solve a problem