# Trying to add cronjob results in ""LICENSE":0: bad minute"

Tags: terminal, catalina, bash, cron, macos

I am trying to set up a cronjob to run every minute with the following command:

`crontab * * * * * sh /Users/username/Downloads/reddit-notifications-master/notifyer.sh`

`notifyer.sh` has the following contents:

```
#!/bin/zsh

python3 /Users/yogesh/Downloads/reddit-notifications-master/reddit_notifications.py
```

When I run the command it says:

```
"LICENSE":0: bad minute
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install
```

Has anyone seen this before? Tried googling but can't find anything on the LICENSE: 0 error.

Comment: `crontab` takes a filename (to read crontab entries from) as an argument, not a raw crontab entry. It also replaces the current crontab (deleting any current entries), rather than just adding new entries to it. I'd recommend using `crontab -l` to see the current contents; and then possibly `crontab -e` to *edit* the current crontab, although the default editor is `vi` and if you're not familiar with it, it's going to be really hard to use.

Comment: `crontab -l` outputs nothing. The crontab contents are currently empty.

Comment: In that case, try `contab -` (note the space and single dash) by itself, then `* * * * * sh /Users/username/Downloads/reddit-notifications-master/notifyer.sh` *on the next line* (as input to the `crontab` program), then Control-D on the next line after that to indicate end-of-input.

Comment: a couple things... `crontab` won’t generate a “license error,” that’s got to be coming from your command.  What happens if you run the command manually.  Second, you’re starting an `sh` shell to then create a ZSH shell with the shebang in your script.  Why not just call the script and let the shebang (`#!/bin/zsh`) handle the shell?

Comment: Also, `cron` has been deprecated in favor of `launchd`. You might want to start migrating to that.  See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a crontab entry by just running `crontab <entry details>`. In your case the shell expands the `*` with whatever filenames it finds in the current directory (which seems to be a file called `LICENSE`, replace `crontab` by `echo` to see what happened to the other `*`'s).

To add new entries to the `crontab` file run

```
export EDITOR=nano
crontab -e
```

add the line

```
* * * * * /Users/username/Downloads/reddit-notifications-master/notifyer.sh
```

directly to the file and save it, then exit the editor again. You can verify that it got added by running `crontab -l`.

Some additional things to consider:

- Run `chmod +x /Users/username/Downloads/reddit-notifications-master/notifyer.sh` to make sure the script is executable
- Run `type python3` in your shell and use the full path you get within `notifyer.sh` to avoid issues with `python3` not being in `PATH`
- If `notifyer.sh` is only used to launch the Python script you don't need the script at all, you can just add

  ```
  * * * * * /path/to/python3 Users/yogesh/Downloads/reddit-notifications-master/reddit_notifications.py
  ```

  to your Crontab instead.