# Periodic System Maintenance: Running as non-root

Tags: terminal, trash

I have had a daily maintenance script to clean out ~/Downloads via the periodic system for years. Recently I decided that I didn't want to delete the files but instead move them to ~/.Trash, allowing me to recover a file in the event I didn't move out of Downloads. The script change was easy, but since it runs as root the script finds the files but cannot move them to ~/.Trash.

The key line of the script is
`find -dx . -fstype local -type f -mtime +7 -exec /usr/local/bin/trash $@ {} + -print`

Documentation of the periodic.conf system is hard to find. Is there a way that I can run a script as myself instead of as root so that the script will work? I've tried `su <user> -c "find -dx . -fstype local -type f -mtime +7 -exec /usr/local/bin/trash $@ {} + -print"` without success.

Anyone out there know some periodic magic?

Comment: Would using a LaunchDaemon instead work as well?

Comment: @nohillside, do you mean using the LaunchDaemon inside the daily script?

Comment: I concur with @nohillside - using a LaunchAgent (runs as user) would run the script with root privileges.  This is done with [`launchd`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271) and configured with a plist.  The other option is to just copy the file to *your* trash folder which is a segue to my next question...  where did `/usr/local/bin/trash` come from?  That's not a folder that comes default.  The Trash is in `~/.Trash` for each user.

Comment: `su` should work fine to drop privileges from root to you. Not sure what  `exec /usr/local/bin/trash $@ {} +` is about but it looks wrong. What is the `$@` for?

Comment: `trash`, installed via homebrew, is a CLI to move files into the user's trashcan. The `-exec /usr/local/bin/trash $@ {} +` is correct, per the `find` manpage and confirmation running directly at the command line. The $@ is a variable using all the files identified by `find`. The entire find command does work from the command line.

Comment: I think one of the issues is Full Disk Access for the script in question. In trying to get it to work with LaunchAgent I've discovered that `find` isn't allowed in the ~/Downloads directory, which is a classic FDA issue.