# Adding a startup script on Big Sur

Tags: command-line, startup, big-sur

I want to install a startup item in OS X Big Sur which runs a shell script as a user on my machine and connects via ssh to a remote machine I maintain.  I use ssh keys so no password is required for this script to succeed.  It will linger in the background.  How would I accomplish this in Big Sur?  My understanding is that the old /Library/Startup Items/xxx.plist trick is deprecated.  What is used in its place?
Thanks!

Comment: Also a potential dupe:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/249446/119271 `launchd` has been the preferred way to run scripts (at any time, not just at login) since `cron` was deprecated.  Whether it's Mavericks, El Cap, Catalina, or Big Sur, `launchd` is the preferred way to go.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac seems to still work on Big Sur. TL;DR; version - use Automator to invoke your script from an Application and add that to your Login Items

Answer (score 3):

<s>Don't have **macOS Big Sur** yet;</s> however, in previous version of **macOS** there is **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > ***you*** > **Login Items**, or use a **Launch Agent**. (I assume these methods are still available in **macOS Big Sur**.)

Have a look at:

- [Open items automatically when you log in on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-items-automatically-when-you-log-in-mh15189/mac)
- [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ)
- See also the *manual pages* for `launchd` and `launchctl` in **Terminal**.

  - <sup>You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`command`* and then *right-click* on it and select: **Open man Page**</sup>

---

### **Update:**

To refute the claim made by Vihung in a comment: "While you answer, in general, is correct, it doesn't apply to shell scripts"

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, show below, used as a *shell script* with a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang*, and added to the **Login Items** *tab* of my account in **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups**, opens a new *window* in **Terminal** with an `ssh` session to another *computer* and automatically closes the original *window* that opened the `ssh` session in the new *window*.

This was tested under **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup> <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

<sup>**Note:** Change `ssh user@hostname` to a properly formed `ssh` *command* for your required usage.</sup>

```applesctipt
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "ssh user@hostname"
    delay 0.5
    close window 2
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Terminal"
        tell its front window
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists button "Terminate" of sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            click button "Terminate" of sheet 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**Notes:**

This requires **Terminal** to be added to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

It also requires **System Events** to be checked under **Terminal** in: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Automation**

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: While you answer, in general, is correct, it doesn't apply to shell scripts

Comment: @Vihung, RE: "While you answer, in general, is correct, it doesn't apply to shell scripts" --   Please see the **Update:** section of my answer, and I'd predicate you retracting your down-vote. Thanks.

Comment: @Vihung, Thank you! If you'd also please remove your comment so I can edit out the  "To refute the claim made by..." line in my updated answer, that would be appreciated.