# How can I access the higher function keys (F16 in particular) on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility

I'm toying around with DOSBox in debugger mode and it seems that in order to break into the debug mode while running I need to run Alt-Pause which on the Mac is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F16</kbd> (see [DOSBoxWiki: Special Keys](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Special_Keys)). However, there is no <kbd>F16</kbd> key on a MacBook Pro; if you hold <kbd>Fn</kbd>, you only get <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Is there some way to either remap a function key or to have access to the higher function keys? Even using the Accessibility keyboard, it doesn't seem to have obvious access to these keys.

Comment: In the opening line of the link you posted - "These are the default keybindings. They can be changed using the [keymapper](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/KeyMapper)."

Comment: Even so, "how to use F13-19 on a laptop or short keyboard" is a great question. I remember trying to find a way to trigger the Clear key on a laptop, and was unable to do so.

Comment: @benwiggy - I'd imagine that would be one for Karabiner, but I've never tried it & all the keyboards here are extended anyway. I'd have thought for a one-off key in a single app, it would be simpler to remap it in there.

Comment: @Tetsujin - yeah, I had missed the note about the remapper utility on that exact page. That said: 1) it isn't working as expected (so I guess I need to ask in the dosbox fora) and 2)  it still is a useful thing to know how to do for cases where there isn't a builtin tool for it.

Comment: [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) seems to be pretty much the de-facto standard for anything like that.

Answer (score 5):

To remap a key, you can use the `hidutil` command.  In this example, I am remapping <kbd>F16</kbd> to the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> on the **right** side (probably not used much, if at all).

[image: MacBook keyboard layout; Opt/Alt Highlighted1]

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping": \
[{\"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000E6, \
"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000006A}]}}
```

<sup>The backslashes (\) allow for a multi-line command to facilitate better readability.  The command can be copied/pasted as-is or the backslashes and new-lines removed to make it a true one-liner.</sup>

When you're writing the command, keep this in mind:

- Src = the key you want to press
- Dst = what you want it to do

I have supplied a portion of the Hex values for the extended function keys as defined in Apple [Technical Note TN240](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) that describes how to use `hidutil`.

| Key | Hex Code | Key | Hex Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Keyboard F13 | 0x68 | Keyboard F19 | 0x6E |
| Keyboard F14 | 0x69 | Keyboard F20 | 0x6F |
| Keyboard F15 | 0x6A | Keyboard F21 | 0x70 |
| Keyboard F16 | 0x6B | Keyboard F22 | 0x71 |
| Keyboard F17 | 0x6C | Keyboard F23 | 0x72 |
| Keyboard F18 | 0x6D | Keyboard F24 | 0x73 |

#### Improving with a script...

To make this complex command easier to work with, I have created a simple Bash script (below) that will allow you to specify the source and destination keys as variables.

I used a function, `mdCMDStr`, to "make the command string" so you can easily replicate additional commands with minimal effort.  Simply, reassign the `SOURCE` and `DEST` variables and call the `mkCMDStr` and `hidutil` commands as many times as necessary.

```
#! /bin/bash



function mkCMDStr () {
# Creates the command string

    SETKEY_CMD={\"UserKeyMapping\":[{\"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc\":${1},\"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst\":${2}}]}

}

SOURCE=0x7000000E6      #Keyboard Right Option/Alt              
DEST=0x70000006A        #Keyboard F16

mkCMDStr $SOURCE $DEST
hidutil property --set "${SETKEY_CMD}"

exit
```

[Download the Script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/du5xzdq5z7wkuu1/setkey.sh?dl=1)

This will **not** persist through reboots.  You can make this "permanent" by putting this script in Login Items or creating a [LaunchAgent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271).

Comment: NSJSONSerialization Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around line 1, column 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around line 1, column 2., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=2}

Comment: Cocoa?  Where are you running this script?

Comment: This is awesome. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to map my Windows keyboard Print Screen (which I think gets interpreted as F13) to anything. For https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/461781/53510, I was thinking maybe since the F13 isn't getting captured by Flameshot, I could use `hidutil` to map Print Screen to something else, and then see if that other key could get monitored by Flameshot.

Comment: The PrintScrn is pretty standard, but they (FlameShot)  may be doing something different.  Can you ask the devs what they are listening for?

Comment: I'll respond to your comment on the other question page. Thanks!