# macOS - can I remap a function key to do nothing

Tags: keyboard, settings

I have minor dexterity problems and I keep hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> when I want <kbd>delete</kbd> (usually I get both as the top  of my finger brushes <kbd>F12</kbd>). I use the <kbd>delete</kbd> key a lot!

Is there a way to disable a function key?

I know how to remap the key to a menu entry so a no-op menu entry would do as well.

Comment: Just a thought, you could remap it to delete as well...

Comment: @SteveChambers What menu item would you map it to? There's no menu entry for Backspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to remap a key to menu item specifically; remap it to a null value or another key. To do this, use  the `hidutil` command to remap <kbd>F9</kbd> to a null value, backspace, or something else.

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":\
[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000045,\
"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000000}]}'
```

<sup>Please note: the backslashes at the end of the lines allow this command to span multiple lines for readability. You can copy/paste this command as is or remove the backslashes for a true one liner</sup>

Now, the source (hex) value of <kbd>F12</kbd> is 0x700000067 and the destination value is 0x700000000.  I haven't tested this particular value but, should it not work, you can use 0x70000002A or 0x7000000E6 for a second backspace (it’s the key you intended to hit anyway), or something like right <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> respectively.

This solution is based on [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/455274/119271) which I previously wrote for a similar question; there are several codes for function keys listed there.  If you need a list of hex codes for additional keys, Apple provides a [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) on `hidutil` for your reference.

Comment: Was it the backslashes?  Let me know what the typos were and I’ll be happy to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @RussellFulton, I fixed per your recommendation.