# Run sshd from Homebrew instead of Ventura's

Tags: homebrew, ssh, launchd

The `ssh` from Ventura 13.3.1 is rather old (OpenSSH_9.0p1); the version I installed from Homebrew is OpenSSH_9.3p1.

The problem is: How can I achieve that `sshd` from Homebrew is run on startup instead of that of Ventura?

I did some digging but I just can't find the .plist that runs it. Can anybody tell me the location?

I know that I have to temporarily disable SIP for the modification; that's no problem for me.

Placing a .plist in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` is not an option because I want to keep port 22.

Comment: It doesn't run from startup.  macOS has an inetd-like facility through launchd that starts sshd as appropriate.  Question... why do you need to run the one from Homebrew?

Comment: @Marc Wilson: I just don't like using outdated software. Do you mean it isn't started directly by launchd but by another daemon?

Comment: Obviously, launchd is the parent of sshd.

Comment: `launchd` is the parent of `sshd`?  That is not correct.  `launchd` manages the starting of daemons and agents much like the old `rc.d` in FreeBSD or  [`inetd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) for Linux or the SMF framework in Solaris.  It just launches jobs, `sshd` is not dependent nor a child process of it.

Comment: See [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/249446/119271) for a brief primer on `launchd` and creating a .plist

Comment: Doesn‘t disabling remote login prevent the standard sshd from starting (and attaching to port 22)?

Comment: @Allan: And what about this? Process:         sshd [8738]
Path:            /usr/sbin/sshd
Load Address:    0x10c5f3000
Identifier:      sshd
Version:         282.100.6
Code Type:       X86-64
Platform:        macOS
Parent Process:  launchd [1] BTW: I merely know systemd from Linux. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @nohillside: A program must run as root to access port 22. I've created a .plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents for /usr/local/sbin/sshd, but this way, it is run under my account and thus cannot access port 22.

Comment: Poor wording on Apple's choice.  You can kill `launchd` and everything will continue to run.  `launchd` was just the bootstrapper.  If you want to run it as root and have it available at all times like the native `sshd`, you need to create a LaunchDaemon.

Comment: @Allan: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: If you want to have it run as root, put it into /Library/LaunchDaemons.

Comment: I'm still wondering why you need to replace it.  `sshd` is started by `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` when something accesses port 22 via tcp.

Comment: @MarcWilson See https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html for the differences between OpenSSH_9.0p1 and OpenSSH_9.3p1. I can understand the intention to have a more recent version of OpenSSH than the one provided by Apple.

Comment: @MarcWilson: Thanks for pointing out; I found it myself in the meantime. It calls /usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper which checks if host keys are present and if not, it creates them and then calls /usr/sbin/sshd. Totally unneccessary to check this each time a connection is made, so by replacing /usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper with /usr/local/sbin/sshd, you not only get the most recent version, but also avoid that stupid check.

Comment: @nohillside: Thanks for backing my stance. As a Debian testing user, I get daily upgrades. And you are right, I like to have things under control instead of relying on Apple.

Comment: Seems as if you have the details figured out now. Can you post an answer summarizing the steps required to use a non-Apple sshd?

Comment: @nohillside: I'd really like to, but even though I've disabled SIP, vi doesn't let me save my changes to ssh.plist. Any advice? Of course, I ran it with sudo.

Comment: Obviously, Apple has changed sth. since Catalina. Disabling SIP doesn't suffice anymore. This is really annoying, but typical for Apple. I'm investigating this.

Comment: You might wanna look up what SSV is.