# Is there a simple way to start a bash script at login or startup WITHOUT revealing the terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash, script, python, startup

I know similar questions have been asked on forums, but due to the constraints of my script, the other solutions are either too complicated or do not work.  Please forgive my lack of knowledge in the topic

I have a small script that starts when the user logs in, and keeps running until the computer is shutdown(or script is terminated).
I configured the script to run like so using "Open Applications at Login" feature on mac.
[image]

But everytime I log in, the terminal is visible and pops up:
[image]

I do not want the terminal to be visible. Instead I want it to be *automatically* hidden when the script starts. It was incredibly simple to achieve this in Windows, but Mac OS makes doing such a simple task incredibly complicated.  I saw many solutions about this topic through the usage of the Automator App in Mac, but my script calls a python command with some arguments, so the terminal still pops up and is visible and can't be automatically hidden even using the Automator App, I have already tried that.

I am using MacOS Monterery. The script only has to run on login for 1 user. I am using the steps mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/995564/1462391) currently. Currently I already have the script running on login, but the terminal is not hidden. Any info pointing me in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: You need this to run as a LaunchAgent using `launchd`. See this  post for an idea how to do this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271

Comment: The SU post you link to has other answers as well, which don’t open a Terminal window.

Comment: hidden_machine: I posted an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/229773/run-command-on-startup-login-mac-os-x/1779178#1779178) based on the answer you linked to. I apologize for not being allowed to ask your question. I think the other users saw your question as the question you linked to and make your question a duplicate based on this. I think they should have spend more time actually reading the question you posted.