# MacBook Pro without battery - nobatterynoproblem.kext permanently

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, kernel-extensions

I have a 2011 MacBook Pro that I use without a battery.
Every time I turn the macbook on, I have to use this kext (https://github.com/balecrim/NoBatteryNoProblem.kext) to improve the velocity of my CPU.
Is there a way to load this kext in a permanent way so I don't have to load it every time I turn the macbook on ?

Comment: Your best course of action is getting a replacement battery. The MBP is designed to run from the battery, not from the power cable.Forcing the CPU to run high with no battery may cause the MBP to shut off.

Comment: thanks for answering ! I've been using the macbook like this for a year without problems. I just want a way to load that kext permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating and loading a LaunchDaemon.

First, create and test a script that loads the kext.  Be certain to use absolute paths to the file(s) you will be referencing in the script.  This is because the PATH won’t be set when this script is run by `launchd`.

Next, create a plist to launch this script and save it to `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.  Refer to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271) for full details on creating the plist. (leave out the *StartCalendarInterval* portion).

Finally, load the plist using `launchctl` (command also found in link above).  This will cause it to run on every boot achieving what you’re after.

Comment: You are THE MAN! thankyouuu!!!