# AppleScript - send a message to the terminal window a bash script is running in, even when that window does not have focus

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I'd like to have my MacOS terminal window change background color while `ssh` is started, and change back to default when `ssh` finishes.  There are a few approaches to this, the one I'm pursuing is to make a little bash function which first uses AppleScript to send a message to the Terminal Window telling it to change profile, then runs ssh, then sends another message via AppleScript telling Terminal to set the profile back.   This approach is described in many posts on the SO family of sites.  It relies on a line like this:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of window 1 to settings set \"$PROFILE_NAME\""
```

This works well *if* ssh exits while the terminal window in question is the focused terminal window.
However, if ssh exits because the remote host closed the connection, it's quite likely that your local window focus has moved to a different terminal window, which means that "window 1", which seems to be 'focused window', is no longer the same terminal window, so you get funky behavior.

Can I grab something like a current terminal window ID at the start and re-use that later ?

Comment: That's very unclear. What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: What exactly is accomplished by sending a message *to* a terminal window?  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: edited for clarity

Comment: Why not display a notification instead.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271) for a method

Comment: because i want to know by the visual appearance of the terminal window whether it is ssh'd into a remote machine.  a notification is interesting, but it's not the same.