# MDM payload to prevent clock changes

Tags: macos, mdm

I'm playing with ways to ensure a system's time (MacOS, 13.4) is synchronized more frequently. The concern is that while I can disable the system time change, a user can still force the time with the command 'date'. I can't remove admin permissions thus I don't think I can block 'date'. If that is true, then I'd like to run the time sync to automatically catch and update the time more frequently, If possible.

In short, I'd like to block ALL changes to time on a system outside of NTP syncing the clock. 2nd to that I'd like a way to reset the time as quickly as possible in the event it is changed.

I'd like to do this as part of an MDM payload but I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: Why not create a script that updates time and put it in a [launchd job to run periodically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271)?

Comment: I’m curious as to why this is a concern because [altering system time can break things](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24711) creating problems for the user.